# Does fio corrupt file system (XFS on mdadm, RAID10)?

Tags: filesystems, mdadm, testing, xfs

I'm doing some intensive testing on a mdadm (software RAID) partition made of 6 SSDs using `fio` (Ubuntu 16.10 Server). The partition was formatted using XFS, is unmounted during tests, contains no files and isn't a boot partition. It happens that sometimes, after a cold start or a reboot, Ubuntu can't complete the boot procedure and stalls on this message:

```
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/8332-B8BE.
[FAILED] Failed to mount /mnt/raid10.
See 'systemctl status mnt-raid10.mount' for details.
```

This is what I get after entering in the recovery mode and issuing `systemctl status mnt-raid10.mount`:

```
mnt-raid10.mount - /mnt/raid10
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mer 2017-02-15 08:18:33 CET; 1h 28min ago
  Where: /mnt/raid10
   What: /dev/md2p1
   Docs: man:fstab(5)
         man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)

systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/raid10...
mount[2064]: mount: mount /dev/md2p1 on /mnt/raid10 failed: La struttura necessita di una pulizia
mnt-raid10.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Failed to mount /mnt/raid10.
mnt-raid10.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

If I launch `xfs_repair /dev/md2p1` Ubuntu boots correctly and I can mount the partition.

The same problem may happen also if I try to mount the partition after testing and before rebooting by executing `mount -t xfs /dev/md2p1 /mnt/raid10`.

I wonder if this is a XFS known issue, a `mdadm` issue or simply its due to `fio` raw writing on the `md` device.

### `fio` configuration

Here is a configuration file (`config.ini`) that I'm using for 4k 100% read/write mix:

```
[4k]
filename=/dev/md2p1
rw=randrw
blocksize=4k
filename=test.bin
ioengine=libaio
iodepth=16
direct=1
invalidate=1
runtime=60
write_bw_log=time_series
write_lat_log=time_series
write_iops_log=time_series
log_avg_msec=1000
numjobs=1
rwmixread=100
refill_buffers=1
norandommap=1
randrepeat=0
per_job_logs=0
description="some text"
```

and here's how I call `fio`:

```
fio config.ini > log.txt
```

`log.txt`, `config.ini` and `test.bin` are located on a different disk device (my home directory, which is a software RAID1 partition on HDDs mounted using `/dev/md1`).

Comment: What do you mean by "`fio` raw writing on the `md` device"?  Are you using `fio` to benchmark the write performance of the raw `md` device *after* building a filesystem on it?

Comment: Also, XFS pretty much requires file system barriers to *work*.  See this older LWN article:  https://lwn.net/Articles/283161/  Are your XFS file system mounted with file system barriers enabled?  If so, are you seeing any log entries *anywhere* indicating file system barriers have been disabled for some reason?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The device is formatted as XFS but is unmounted during testing. For this reason I guess `fio` writes "raw" data (doesn't pass through the FS level) and so corrupts the FS. I'm using `fio` to read and write 4k and 8k chunk sizes. Also, I didn't specify any mount option except from `defaults`.

Comment: Post your `fio` configuration and the command you run the test. If you are writing to the raw disk ( `/dev/md2p1` ) it doesn't matter if the filesystem is mounted or not, the filesystem will be trashed after your test.

Comment: @Thomas I've updated my question. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your `fio` benchmark against the raw blockdevice `/dev/md2p1`, which thrashes your filesystem information.

To avoid that, you should use a file in the filesystem for your benchmark.

```
[4k]
filename=/mnt/raid10/fio.bench
rw=randrw
...
```